# Animation Queue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I'm hoping this is something simple and small that I'm missing, but currently, This code I have applies the animation to all three divs at once, Where as I need one to animate, then once it's finished apply the second animation, then apply the third once that's finished.

Here's what I have:

```
container.live('mouseenter',function(){ 
    $('.pop1').animate({ marginTop: '0px'}, 'slow').next().animate({marginTop: '0px'}, 'slow').animate({marginTop: '0px'}, 'slow');
});
```

Someone please help! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
container.live('mouseenter',function() {
    var slideUp = function (el) {
      if (el.length) {
        el.animate({ marginTop: '0px' }, 'slow', function () { 
          slideUp(el.next()); 
        });
      }
    };

    slideUp($('.pop1'));
});
```

Comment: Hey, Thankyou! This works, although now it's just a css problem, Is there a way to align 3 divs, without using " display: Inline-block with it's parent set to text-align:center;" If I float the elements, the script works, but if I use inline-block, they only "slide" up when the last one's margins are animated. 

Please help! see here: http://www.shannonhochkins.com and hover over my name up the top, thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

```
container.live('mouseenter',function(){ 
    $('.pop1').animate({ marginTop: '0px'}, 'slow', function() {
        $(this).next().animate({marginTop: '0px'}, 'slow', function() {
             $(this).next().animate({marginTop: '0px'}, 'slow')
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi @gabitzish, This still does the animation to all three elements at the same time: http://www.shannonhochkins.com/#home  If you hover over my name at the top of the document, you'll see what I'm talking about. The three different elements are "3D Graphics", "&", and "Technical Artist"

Yet they all move at the same time. 

Shannon

Comment: Whoops, It does work, however now it's a css problem, it's because the items are "display:block" and the parent is set to text align center. 

Your script does work, but is there a way to align the 3 divs to the center without using display block? or absolute positioning? I just think it's a bit dodgy using absolute positioning. Cheers